# ¿Como saber si la peticion es por ajax o por navegador? LARAVEL 5.7

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, laravel-5

tengo una consulta, tengo mi ajax de la siguiente manera:

```
function objetoAjax() {
            var xmlhttp = false;
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (E) {
                    xmlhttp = false;
                }
            }
            if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            return xmlhttp;
        }
```

****AQUI EMPIEZA MI PETICION********

```
    ajax = objetoAjax();
    ajax.open('GET', '/proceso/'+proceso);
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            var mensaje = ajax.responseText;
        };
    }
    ajax.send();
```

****AHORA ESTA ES MI RUTA EN LARAVEL***

```
Route::get('/proceso/{proceso?}','ProcesosController@index')->where('proceso', '[a-z]+')->name('proceso');
```

¿Como detecto que la peticion hacia esa ruta es realmente por ajax o se esta ejecutando desde el mismo navegador? Lo que deseo es que esas rutas solo se ejecuten por ajax, si alguien lo pone en el navegador, quisiera bloquear su acceso.

Answer (score 2):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
        return "Se ejecuta desde ajax";
    }else{
        return "se ejecuta desde navegador";
    }
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que debes importar el controlador:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Te edito en la respuesta el comentario importante de **Pablo Lozano**:

> Importante: esta función se basa en encontrar 'X-Requested-With' como header. JQuery y otras librerías añaden este header en cada petición AJAX, pero si la petición la estás haciendo de manera manual, debes añadir manualmente dicho header o no se detectará como petición AJAX

Teniendo esto en cuenta debes agregar `ajax.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");` a tu **JS** antes de enviar la petición, quedando tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
ajax = objetoAjax();
ajax.open('GET', '/proceso/'+proceso);
ajax.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
        var mensaje = ajax.responseText;
    };
}
ajax.send();
```

Comment: Importante: esta función se basa en encontrar `'X-Requested-With'` como header. JQuery y otras librerías añaden este header en cada petición AJAX, pero si la petición la estás haciendo de manera manual, debes añadir manualmente dicho header o no se detectará como petición AJAX

Comment: @PabloLozano gracias por esta aclaración tan importante, he editado la respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

Para comprobar que la peticion sea por `ajax` acá te dejo un código simple que podrá ayudarte.

```
         /**       
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @param  Illuminate\Http\Request $request
         * @return Response
         */
        public function index(Request $request)
        {
            if($request->ajax()){
                return "AJAX";
            }
            return "HTTP";
        }
```

Comment: Ya probé pero cuando hago la petición por ajax me sale lo mismo que cuando lo hago por el navegador. Existe alguna otra función?